# Acumatica how to expose Line Note Text to Inventory Allocation Details screen

Tags: acumatica

Has anyone try to customize Inventory Allocation Details screen? I want to get the line Note Text to show up in the grid either the icon that you can hover over or a custom field with the line note text from PO and SO.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it by extending InventoryAllocDetEnqResult with 2 unbound fields (UsrNoteSO & UsrNotePO).

```
namespace PX.Objects.IN
{
  public class InventoryAllocDetEnqResultExt : PXCacheExtension<InventoryAllocDetEnqResult>
  {
    #region UsrNoteSO
    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="UsrNoteSO")]
    public virtual string UsrNoteSO { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrNoteSO: PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrNoteSO> { }
    #endregion
      
    #region UsrNotePO
    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="UsrNotePO")]
    public virtual string UsrNotePO { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrNotePO: PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrNotePO> { }
    #endregion
  }

  public class InventoryAllocDetEnq_Extension : PXGraphExtension<InventoryAllocDetEnq>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
    public delegate void ProcessItemPlanRecAsDelegate(Type planTypeInclQtyField, List<InventoryAllocDetEnqResult> resultList, ItemPlanWithExtraInfo itemPlanWithExtraInfo);
    [PXOverride]
    public void ProcessItemPlanRecAs(Type planTypeInclQtyField, List<InventoryAllocDetEnqResult> resultList, ItemPlanWithExtraInfo itemPlanWithExtraInfo, ProcessItemPlanRecAsDelegate baseMethod)
    {
      baseMethod(planTypeInclQtyField,resultList,itemPlanWithExtraInfo);
      // Get last item from resultList
      // Update UsrNoteSO and UsrNotePO
    }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

Hope this snippet helps.